# xlrd data extraction python

Tags: python, xlrd

I am working on data extraction using xlrd and I have extracted 8 columns of inputs for my project. Each column of data has around 100 rows. My code is as follows:

```
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('/Users/Documents/Sample_data/AI_sample.xlsx')

sh = wb.sheet_by_name('Sample')

x1 = sh.col_values( + 0)[1:]
x2 = sh.col_values( + 1)[1:]
x3 = sh.col_values( + 2)[1:]
x4 = sh.col_values( + 3)[1:]
x5 = sh.col_values( + 4)[1:]
x6 = sh.col_values( + 5)[1:]
x7 = sh.col_values( + 6)[1:]
x8 = sh.col_values( + 7)[1:]
```

Now I want to create an array of inputs which gives each row of the 8 columns. 
For eg: if this is my 8 columns of data

```
x1   x2   x3   x4   x5   x6   x7   x8   
1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
7    8    6    5    2    4    8    8
9    5    6    4    5    1    7    5   
7    5    6    3    1    4    5    6
```

i want something like: x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6 ([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]) for all the 100+ rows.

I could have done a row wise extraction but, doing that for 100+ rows is practically very difficult. So how do i do that. i also understand that it could be done using np.array. but i do not know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this piece of code very useful

```
X = np.array([x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8])
return X.T
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try **openpyxl** something similar to **xlrd**

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook,Workbook
book  = load_workbook(filename=file_name)
sheet = book['sheet name']
for row in sheet.rows:
    col_0           = row[0].value
    col_1           = row[1].value
```

I used to prefer openpyxl instead of xlrd